# Try::Tiny and $SIG{__DIE__} in perl?

Tags: perl

Is it possible to use Try::Tiny in a Perl program that has a 'overloaded' `$SIG{__DIE__}`?
For example, the desired output of this program would be "caught it":

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Try::Tiny;

# here how to deal with try and catch 
$SIG{__DIE__} =
  sub { 
       print "died my way $_[0]"
};

my $rv;
try {die "its only a flesh wound"; }
catch { 
    $rv = undef; 
    print "caught it: $_ ";
};
```

Thanks for looking and any advice!

Comment: If you do not mind using a different module, you can use [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try) as a drop-in replacement and you would not have to worry about SIG DIE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The docs for `$SIG{__DIE__}` show [`$^S`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%5ES) being used for a reason: You almost always want to use `$^S` in `__DIE__` handlers to avoid the problem you are asking about.

For example,

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Try::Tiny;

$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
   return if $^S;                      # If in eval.
   print(STDERR "Died: $_[0]");        # Send msg to STDERR, not STDOUT.
   exit( $! || ( $? >> 8 ) || 255 );   # Emulate die().
};

try {
   die("It's only a flesh wound.");
} catch {
   print("Caught: $_");
};

die("More than a flesh wound");

print("done.\n");
```

outputs

```
Caught: It's only a flesh wound. at a.pl line 14.
Died: More than a flesh wound at a.pl line 19.
```

Answer (score 5):

`Try::Tiny` is mostly a syntactic sugar wrapper for an `eval` call, and a `die` call inside an `eval` block will call a `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler. The authors [anticipated your objection](https://metacpan.org/release/Try-Tiny/source/lib/Try/Tiny.pm#L605), but ultimately decided to stick with the legacy behavior.

> Though it can be argued that `$SIG{__DIE__}` should be disabled inside of
> `eval` blocks, since it isn't people have grown to rely on it. Therefore in
> the interests of compatibility, `try` does not disable `$SIG{__DIE__}` for
> the scope of the error throwing code.

But feel free to disable it yourself

```
try {
   local $SIG{__DIE__};
   ...
} catch { ... };
```

or rewrite `try .. catch` to do what you want.

```
sub my_try (&;@) {
    my ($try, @code_refs) = @_;
    local $SIG{__DIE__};
    Try::Tiny::try($try,@code_refs);
}
```